# Stimulus Payments Increased the Tax Owed

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, stimulus

I am using Turbo Tax to file my taxes for 2020. In Turbo Tax it asked if I received stimulus payments and how many. I received one payment in May 2020 and one payment in January 2021. I entered both payments in Turbo Tax and suddenly my tax owed jump $3000.

Any ideas why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stimulus payment was a tax credit paid to you in advance. The amount you received in stimulus payments has a direct 1:1 relationship with your tax liability. Assuming you are eligible for the tax credit, if you had not been paid the stimulus, your tax liability would go down by the amount you should have been paid, but weren’t.

Comment: In other words, Turbo Tax assumes that you did *not* get the stimulus at first. Once the OP said that they got $3,000 cumulative from the stimulus payments, the tax owed goes up 1:1 (unless there are other un-filled deductions/credits).

Comment: @Nosjack [I don’t use TurboTax](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/59/83), so I don’t know the timing of when in the interview it decides whether or not to include the credit in its tax bill estimate. But regardless, if you do your taxes telling it you got $0 stimulus, and you do your taxes again telling it you got $3000 stimulus, the difference between the two runs would be $3000.

Comment: I received 2 stimulus checks totaling around $5000. Right at the end Turbo Tax asks to enter both checks. When I write it then I owe more in taxes. I thought they are not going to tax the stump checks. I am in USA

Comment: @azamsharp You are not taxed on the stimulus checks. You (and most taxpayers) get a tax credit (tax reduction) for 2020. The stimulus payment gave you that money early, so you didn’t have to wait for your tax refund in 2021 to receive it. If you hadn’t gotten the payment then, it would be used now to reduce your tax payment (or increase your refund).

Comment: @azamsharp To explain another way: This tax credit is new; it did not exist last year. Your tax bill now is what it would have been if the pandemic had never occurred, and the stimulus check you received was essentially “free money” from the government. (So to speak. Nothing from the government is free.)

Comment: I am failing to understand that why when I enter the stimulus amount, the money I owe to IRS goes up. If I remove the stimulus amount the tax that I owe goes down.

Comment: @azamsharp Imagine that you never received the stimulus money. You would have a certain tax bill, which you see in TurboTax before you enter the stimulus payment. Now imagine that the government gave you money last year that you need to pay back this year. That is essentially what you are seeing.

Comment: @azamsharp I don’t know the details of your tax situation, so I don’t know why your tax bill is so high. You are supposed to be paying tax all year so you don’t have a large tax bill at tax time.

Comment: @azamsharp An example with numbers: Imagine that the pandemic never happened and there was no tax credit or stimulus. Let’s say that your tax bill was $4,000. Now add in the pandemic and the government gives you a tax credit of $3,000. Now your tax bill is only $1,000, but you need to wait until tax time (spring of 2021) to see the benefit. Now let’s say the government gives you a $3,000 loan in spring of 2020, but you need to pay it back on your next tax bill. You receive the $3,000, and your tax bill is now at the original $4,000.

Comment: @azamsharp Based on your comments, it sounds like you received $5000 in stimulus payments, but your 2020 tax credit ended up being only $3000. That can happen, and you don’t need to pay back the extra money you received. It is yours to keep.

Comment: It seems poor design for TurboTax to assume that you didn't get any stimulus checks for the initial estimate before asking you the question (if that's what the OP is claiming). The estimate should be based on the common case, and the common case is that people received their stimulus checks.

Comment: The way I see it, I received two stimulus checks totaling around $5K and now the IRS wants it back. Whats the point of giving stimulus checks if you are going to take it back?

Comment: @azamsharp It’s not that the IRS wants it back. Remember, that tax credit is new; it didn’t exist last year. Your tax bill is the same as it would have been without any pandemic/tax credit/stimulus, yet you received $5000 last year for nothing.

Comment: Try this - I made too much in 2018/19 to get a dime. Tax software says I get $3600 tax credit for 2020 return. Nice. But if I tell the software I already got, say, $3600 already, that credit goes away. Now, if my tax return would otherwise have been a net $3600 "owed", the tax credit cancels that out. But if I got the $3600 checks already, I'd owe the $3600 regular tax bill. Not the $3600 stimulus payment.